# Retrieve which button was clicked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have several dynamically generated material UI buttons, and when user clicks any of them I would like to know which was clicked (let's say obtain the value of `name` attribute which I assigned below).
How can this be solved? Basically I want to retrieve some attribute of the button which was clicked.
Here is some code

```
    {
      that.state.items.map(function (item) {
        return (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <FlatButton
              label={item.regionName}
              name={item.id}
              primary={true}
              onClick={that.handleRegionClick}
            ></FlatButton>
          </div>
        );
      });
    }
    
    handleRegionClick(e);
    {
      console.log(e.target.name); // This prints undefined
      // If I could get here the _item.id_ which I assigned to _name_ I would be fine.
    }
```

PS. I also have this in constructor

```
 this.handleRegionClick = this.handleRegionClick.bind(this);
```

Comment: one ques, how you are generating the button dynamically, inside any loop ?

Comment: @MayankShukla Yes in map

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do one thing, instead of assigning the id to name, `bind` that id with `onClick` handler function. Whenever any of the button will be clicked, it will pass that id to handler function.

Like this:

```
let a = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

a.map(item => {

   return <FlatButton
    label={item.regionName}
    primary={true}
    onClick={() => this.handleRegionClick(item.id)} />

})
```

`handleRegionClick` function:

```
handleRegionClick(id){
  console.log(id);
}
```

**Note:** binding of `handleRegionClick` is not required here because here, we are using `arrow function` with onClick and calling `handleRegionClick` normally.

Comment: This works:   onClick={() => that.handleRegionClick(item.id)} (use that instead of this in my case inside render)

Comment: Perfect idea, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your question looks weird to me. You can simply do it.

```
<FlatButton label={item.regionName} name={item.id} primary={true} onClick={that.handleRegionClick.bind(this, item.id)}></FlatButton>

handleRegionClick(itemId){
  console.log(itemId)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `onClick` for this. Instead, when you generate the button, add an event listener. If you do that, then you can access the clicked element through `e.toElement` and access its name property with `e.toElement.name` (seems like your `item.id` is in the name property).

```
for (...) { // however many buttons you generate
    var x = generateButtonSomehow(); // make sure it returns the DOM element
    x.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log(e.toElement.name);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe trying to bind that.handleRegionClick() to this?

`that.handleRegionClick.bind(that)`

Then you should be able to access `e.target`

Comment: `e.target` gives me the form... not the button that was clicked.