# How to get the childNode index onClick in React in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, react-functional-component

Coinsider the code below

```
function getChildIndex(){
//logic here
}

//render 
<div>
{Array.from({length: 3}).map((item,index) => (
            <div onClick={getChildIndex}/> 
        )
        )}
</div>
```

it will render as follow

```
<div>
     <div> //with click event // 1st Child
     <div> //with click event // 2nd Child
     <div> //with click event // 3rd Child
</div>
```

How can i get the child element number when i click the child element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve which button was clicked React/Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604167/retrieve-which-button-was-clicked-react-material)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` is available as 2nd argument of `map's` callback function as you also showed. Just use it as required like so:-

`<div onClick={()=>doSomethingWithIndex(index)}/>`

Comment: i tried using the above but i'm getting error ,
TypeError : doSomethingWithIndex is not a function
i am passing it as props and lifting state up to parent

Comment: I hope the parent has a function named doSomethingWithIndex or infact anything you like.

Comment: Sorry your solution is correct , i din't notice i forgot to pass the props in midde level component, instead passed only on very top level only